# What does a golang for { ..block.. } without conditions do?

Tags: go

I'm a golang neophyte and I've come across a rather interesting control structure which doesn't follow the classical imperative for-loop construct.  I've been unable to locate on documentation on the structure either. The following is the code in question:

```
  for {
    // read each incoming message
    m, err := getMessage(ws)
    if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
    }   

    // see if we're mentioned
    if m.Type == "message" && strings.HasPrefix(m.Text, "<@"+id+">") {
      // if so try to parse if
      ans := lookup(session, m.Text)
      if len(ans)>0 {
        // looks good, get the quote and reply with the result
        go func(m Message) {
          for _, def := range ans {
            if len(def[1]) > 0 { 
              m.Text = "*" + def[0] + " " + def[1] + "*: " + def[2]
            } else {
              m.Text = "*" + def[0] + "*: " + def[2]
            }   
            postMessage(ws, m)
            }   
        }(m)
        // NOTE: the Message object is copied, this is intentional
      } else {
        // huh?
        m.Text = fmt.Sprintf("sorry, that does not compute\n")
        postMessage(ws, m)
      }   
    }   
  }
```

Does the loop construct just loop forever or is there an eventing system binding behind the scenes?

Comment: *Does the loop construct just loop forever* Yes.

Comment: In the [Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/3) and in [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [For statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)
>
> A "for" statement specifies repeated execution of a block. The
>   iteration is controlled by a condition, a "for" clause, or a "range"
>   clause.
>
> ```
> ForStmt = "for" [ Condition | ForClause | RangeClause ] Block .
> Condition = Expression .
> ```
>
> In its simplest form, a "for" statement specifies the repeated
>   execution of a block as long as a boolean condition evaluates to true.
>   The condition is evaluated before each iteration. If the condition is
>   absent, it is equivalent to the boolean value true.

If the condition is absent, for example, `for { ... }`, it is equivalent to the boolean value `true`, for example `for true { ... }`. It is sometimes referred to as an infinite loop. Therefore, you will need another mechanism, such as `break` or `return`, to terminate the loop.

The documentation for the `for` statement is the [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).

Comment: does return inside of a for loop take precedence over return of the function?  i.e. the function will need another return if it is looking for one?

Comment: i took a look at the golang spec (amazingly readable!).  my understanding is that return is for the containing function - in this case it breaks the loop by terminating the containing function itself.  break is for terminating an inner for loop, which terminates the loop.  maybe this was obvious but i am so new i can't take anything for granted.

Comment: In Go, as in other languages, "A "return" statement in a function F terminates the execution of F." https://golang.org/ref/spec

Answer (score 13):

`for` without any additional statements is basically the same as `while (true)` in other languages, an infinite loop.